# How do I respond to an HTTP get request with Python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, get

The webhook I am building needs to respond to an HTTP GET request, with a body containing the value of a query parameter.

The HTTP GET looks like this:

GET https://example.com?challenge=8ec8d794-e0ab-42df-9017-e3dada8e84f7

This PHP script works...

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/plain');
 echo $_GET['challenge']; 
?>
```

How would I replicate this in Python? Ideally without having to execute the PHP script within Python.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to write a web server, or a WSGI (or FCGI or CGI or mod_python) script that plugs into a webserver. Or, a lot more simply, just pick something like Flask up off the shelf to be the web server or WSGI middleware, and just write a simple Flask handler instead of writing the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks I have a flask, but struggling to see how I would recreate the php script in Python language?

Comment: Then work through the “getting started” tutorial for Flask. To explain it, I’d have to essentially rewrite that tutorial, and I wouldn’t do nearly as good a job.

Comment: Thanks, i've been playing around with this most of this evening and managed to get it to work.